# Wordpress customizer preview scripts perform live preview on initial page load and not while I navigate inner pages from the preview window

Tags: javascript, wordpress

Thanks for stopping by.
I'm working on a wordpress theme with custom customizer controls. Everything works fine so far. I'm also adding a live preview so users see what they change

```
var api = wp.customize;
api('site_logo_alt_font_size', function (value) {
    value.bind(function (newval) {
        $('#vineyard-logo').css('font-size', newval + 'px');
    });
});
```

This seems to work fine. The issue I have is that when I click on any link (on the navigation menu for instance) within my preview window, the live preview seems to stop. I can tell it doesn't really reload the page. It does some sort of ajax reload. So the bottom line is that the amazing live preview functionality only works when you land on the customizer page as long as you don't click any link withing the customizer preview window. Can anyone help with that? I would be most grateful.

**Additional Info:**
The firebug console is clean, no js errors. However I can tell from the network tab on firebug that, the customizer scripts seem to be fetched once on initial page load and not while I click on links on the customizer window.This is how my scripts are added

```
add_action('customize_preview_init', 'my_customize_preview_init', 100);
function my_customizer_preview_init (){ //my wp_enqueue_script goes here  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue. I solved it by editing the handle 'mytheme-themecustomizer' to a **unique** 'divi-child-theme-customizer' in the enqueue statement, and it worked. I don't see your enqueue statement, so no telling if it will work in your case.

From:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 
          'mytheme-themecustomizer',            //Give the script an ID
          get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/js/theme-customizer.js',//Point to file
          array( 'jquery','customize-preview' ),    //Define dependencies
          '',                       //Define a version (optional) 
          true                      //Put script in footer?
    );
```

To:

```
wp_enqueue_script( 
          'divi-child-theme-customizer',            //Give the script an ID
          get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/js/theme-customizer.js',//Point to file
          array( 'jquery','customize-preview' ),    //Define dependencies
          '',                       //Define a version (optional) 
          true                      //Put script in footer?
    );
```

https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Customization_API